# Distribution of the sum of two independent normal variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given the two variables $A\sim \text{N}(\mu, \phi^2)$ and $B\sim \text{N}(\xi, \omega^2)$ with $\mu, \xi \in R$ and $\phi^2, \omega^2 > 0$ how do I prove that $C := A + B\sim \text{N}(\mu + \xi, \phi^2 + \omega^2)$ ?

Comment: You want the normality of the sum of independent normals. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variable.

Comment: @deinst An "s" is missing in the link. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables

Comment: Please  search using the keywords from your question (e.g., sum, independent, normal) before posting it. See [ask].

Answer (score 1):

in case they are independent use Characteristic functions:
$$\phi_{A+B} (t) = \phi_{A}(t) \phi_{B}(t)$$
and it is easy to see that $\phi_{A}(t)$ looks like char. function. of $N(\mu+\xi,  \omega^{2}+\phi^{2})$